# How to download specific file from FTP server using WinSCP?

Tags: batch-file, winscp

How to copy data from FTP by name file?

I have a script like this, but this script download all files that do not exist or are modified:

```
open Regional4
synchronize local "D:\FTP\pendidikan\sekolah" "/Reg_4/sekolah/2016"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get).

```
get "/Reg_4/sekolah/2016/the_file.ext" "D:\FTP\pendidikan\sekolah\"
```

Comment: get -neweronly "/Reg_4/sekolah/2016/" "D:\FTP\pendidikan\sekolah\"

Comment: Well, you didn't wrote that you want to download the file only if it has changed. If that's the case, you can indeed use the `-neweronly` switch.